# how to find the relationship between 2nd degree friends with spring data neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

[my relationship graph as below pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPlvj.png)
Using `MATCH (n:Person {name:'1'})-[]-()-[r]-(m) RETURN m,r` will return "4" and "5",but **cannot get the relationship between "4" and "5"**,actually,"4" follow "5","r" just represent the friends of 4(4-->2) and 5(5-->3).

In spring data neo4j
**domain.java**

```
@NodeEntity(label = "Person")
public class PersonTest {
@Id
private Long id;
@Property(name = "name")
private String name;
@Relationship(type = "Follow")  //direction=Relationship.DIRECTION
private List<PersonTest> friends;
```

**Repository.java**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Neo4jRepository<PersonTest,Long> {
    @Query("MATCH (n:Person {name:{name}})-[]-()-[r]-(m) RETURN m,r")
    Collection<PersonTest> graph(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

**Service.java**

```
 Collection<PersonTest> persons = personRepository.graph(name);
 Iterator<PersonTest> result = persons.iterator();
 while (result.hasNext()) {
      for (PersonTest friend : p.getFriends()) {
           //........here will get 2 and 3!
      }
 }
```

How to resolve this problem??get the relationship between "4" and "5".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find related children at a certain level, you can use a two-sided pattern of variable length:

```
MATCH (n:Person {name:'1'})-[:Follow*2]->(m)-[r:Follow]-()<-[:Follow*2]-(n) 
RETURN m,r
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/el2x80

**Update**. I think that this is a more correct query:

```
MATCH (n:Person {name:'1'})-[:Follow*2]->(m:Person)-[r:Follow]-(k:Person) 
WHERE (n)-[:Follow*2]->(k) 
RETURN m, r
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/bv2u8k

Comment: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=tbvdc5 in this model with spring data neo4j,go through "r" collection, will get nodes "6",in this scene, i do not need "6"

Comment: how to get the relationship between all nodes?